# How To: PHP elseIf to change div depending on the URL Contents

Tags: php, url, if-statement

**Issue:** I have a php file that I do not have access to but I need to be able to format it. It generates several different pages depending on the search. I have been able to change a div using php if else statements in the header that the php calls to. (See Below)

What I would like to do is have a statement that will change the div depending on what is in the url, now the issue with this is that one of the pages I need to change, has the "submitIt" in the url which is what I am using to change the first div.

I have tried to change the code so that it calls to a different portion of the url but because the url still contains the first bit "submitIt" it calls to that div, rather than the new div.

Is there a way to call the elseif statement where if it contains "submitIt and "MEDIA_TYPE_ID" then it would print out the new div?

```
<?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (strpos($url, "submitIt"))  {
echo '<div style="width:560px;" class="app-h3 app-table">';
}elseif (strpos($url, "MEDIA_TYPE_ID"))  {
echo '<div style="width:560px;" class="app-h3 app-table-none">';
}else {
echo '<div style="width:560px;" class="app-h3">';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `&&` operator. It means 'and'.

```
if (strpos($url, "submitIt") && strpos($url, "MEDIA_TYPE_ID")) {
    // do something
}
```

If both of those are true, it will execute the code block.

Comment: thank you for your help. That works great except that the line:

    if (strpos($url, "submitIt"))  {

Overwrites it. I need to be able to call to a div with one statement and then another with the new statement that you gave me...
<br />

`<?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 if (strpos($url, "submitIt"))  {
    echo '<div style="width:560px;" class="app-h3 app-table">hello';
 }elseif (strpos($url, "submitIt") && strpos($url, "MEDIA_TYPE_ID"))  {
    echo '<div style="width:560px;" class="app-h3 app-table">snort';
 }else {
    echo '<div style="width:560px;" class="app-h3">';
 }
?>`

Comment: This is just a simple use of how to use the `&&` operator. You will need to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Ok, so would it be possible to do a statement like this that says if the url contains: submitIt but does not contain MEDIA_TYPE_ID then do this...
Something like this?
`if (strpos($url, "submitIt")==true && strpos($url, "MEDIA_TYPE_ID")==false  {`

Comment: Think logically about the order you want to check things in. The if statement will match on the FIRST thing it can, not the most specific.

Comment: You Rock Justin. Thank you for your help and for taking the time to tutor me! It is working. Have a great day. 8-)